# What is the best way of converting an array to array of objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to turn this...

```
var data1 = ['Test1', 'Test2'];
```

... into this:

```
var data2 = [{
    name: 'Test1',
    type: {
        id: 'TEST'
    }
}, {
    name: 'Test2',
    type: {
        id: 'TEST'
    }
}];
```

Comment: Have you tried the worst way?

Comment: How exactly should a program know each item's `id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't really a shortcut. You simply loop through and produce the new array. On ES5-enabled systems, you can use `Array#map`:

```
var data2 = data1.map(function(entry) {
    return {
        name: entry,
        type: {
            id: "TEST"
        }
    };
});
```

`Array#map` can be shimmed on earlier engines (search for "es5 shim" for several options), or you can simply use a standard `for` loop:

```
var index;
var data2 = [];
for (index = 0; index < data1.length; ++index) {
    data2.push({
        name: data1[index],
        type: {
            id: "TEST"
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, both work great.

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla JS, old compatible version:

```
function convertArrayToObject(array) {
    var obj = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        obj.push({
            name: array[i],
            type: {
                id: 'TEST'
            }
        });
    }
    return obj;
}
```